# Devise Error on upgrading to rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Currently I am using Rails 4.0.8 to implement my rails app. Now I want to upgrade to rails 4.2, in this app of mine I am using Devise and OmniAuth for authentication and it is working fine for rails 4.0.8.
Now when I try to upgrade to rails 4.2.3 all of a sudden my authentication system stopped working. It is giving the following errors

```
ArgumentError at /users/auth/facebook/callback
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) and it is pointing to the line in controller sign_in_and_redirect(user)
```

The code for my OmniAuth callback controller is :

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
def all
    p env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = "You are in..!!! Go to edit profile to see the status for the accounts"
        sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

  def failure
  #handle you logic here..
  #and delegate to super.
  super
end


    alias_method :facebook, :all
    alias_method :google_oauth2, :all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem in an [**sign_in_and_redirect()**](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers%3Asign_in_and_redirect) method, it is allows two arguments `resource` and `event`, fix your code to:

```
def all
  p env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
  if user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = "You are in..!!! Go to edit profile to see the status for the accounts"
    sign_in_and_redirect(user, event: :authentication)
  else
    session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```